# How to screen share using slack and wayland in Manjaro Gnome?

Tags: gnome, manjaro, pipewire, slack-desktop

On Manjaro, I have installed `com.slack.Slack` in version `4.23.0` through flatpak.

Now, when I try to share a screen, I unexpectedly get a "Screen Share" popup that appears to be coming from Gnome. I expect to not see that at all but that I can select the app / screen directly from the underlaying slack Share Screen popup.

[image: Overlay Screen Share that does not react to user input]

The additional Screen Share popup would be fine, yet it also does not react on clicks. I cannot Cancel, Share and cannot even a select a screen nor an entire screen.

How to properly enable screen share?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1221333/screensharing-under-wayland

Answer (score 2):

You can interact with the Gnome pop-ups but they are in a stack and only the topmost is responsive. Find it by using ***Super*** + ***backtick*** to cycle between them. This requires some trial and error. To close them, you must close the topmost first, then the others in order.

Comment: Thanks. While I still consider this a workaround it at least made me able to close all the superfluous windows.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the Zoom Flatpak, where I couldn't share the screen due to the Wayland/Flatpak combo. I solved this by installing a handy GUI called `flatseal` from flathub.

Inside `flatseal`, you can set the permissions on the various `flatpak` applications; this includes a pass-through to for the application to access other software running on your Wayland session.

To do this:

1. Run `flatpak install flathub com.github.tchx84.Flatseal` in the terminal.
2. Exit the application you are going to set the permissions for.
3. Open the application and navigate to the desired application in the left-side navigation menu.
4. Under 'Socket' there is a radio button which says 'Wayland windowing system' - click to enable it.
5. Open the application and see if it works.

If you'd rather not install anything else, you can open `$HOME/.var/app/<YOUR.APP>/config/<YOUR.APP>.conf`, and edit the file manually.

Comment: Alas for slack I don't see any different effect after changing the socket setting.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but a workaround to at least get a screen share going:

- click on the underlaying slack popup
- chose entire screen
- now the Share Screen overlay pops up again and can be interacted with

[image: Slack Share your Screen popup]

---

This still has the problem that a lot of dead "Screen Share" windows are opened that can't be interacted with nor closed.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a Linux **display server** issue : check which display server you are using : `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` : it may be displayed **Wayland** if you have this problem. Indeed, this display server often have issues.

So I advise you to change your display server to X11 (also called Xorg):

- **Temporarily** : Log out from your session, and on the lock screen, click on the settings button and select a X11 or Xorg field.
- **or by default**:

  - edit this config file :`sudo nano /etc/gdm/custom.conf`
  - Under the [daemon] section, uncomment or add this : `WaylandEnable=false`
  - You may have to restart your laptop

This will change your display server to X11 and it should fix your screen sharing.

---

Get to know more about what is a display server : [**here**](https://itsfoss.com/display-server/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20display%20server%20in,your%20computer%20graphically%20(GUI).)

Sources : [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73397079/screen-share-not-working-in-ubuntu-22-04-showing-black-screen-with-slack-googl) and [**here**](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/configuring-xorg-as-default-gnome-session/)

:)